# Single Record View, like PL/SQL Developer

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Is there any way to show result pane in SQL Server like PL/SQL Developer, option Single Record View?

PL/SQL Developer print example:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unfortunately Sql Server Management Studio does not provide that option.

Comment: just [how difficult can that be](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3ad169c8-b4d4-4f03-929c-c1910a96f713/single-record-view-in-sql-server-management-studio-2005?forum=sqltools&prof=required), let's write a plugin.

Comment: I spotted some comments over here:  https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2227126-looking-for-a-form-or-front-end-solution-to-enter-edit-data-into-sql-database    suggests Excel or MSAccess as options ..   You would think someone would have created a free tool to do this?